# SQL isnull error

Tags: sql, sybase, isnull

While trying to do a select query using the isnull which, i've tried in 2 differents servers that are identical one to the other. (They both use the same procedure, dll, return page, they just change from one ip to the other)

```
SELECT * FROM
ITEM_TEST
WHERE ITEM_NAME = isnull(@ITEM_TESTE, ITEM_NAME)
```

The operation is working without problems in one of the servers, returning all options when the @ITEM_TESTE is NULL, while in the other, it returns ONLY the ones that are NOT NULL. 
I'm using a sybase-based-application (version 12.5) called SQLdbx (version 3.14)

Case it's not so openly understood, @ITEM_TESTE is a variable given from the user that is optional, meaning it can be null where the ITEM_NAME accepts a STRING to it, while it's also option the ITEM_TEST is a table with more than 10 variables, i'm simplifing it. This search, however, want's all the possibles results even if ITEM_NAME is UNKOWN while using others variables to narrow down the search. (I thought about creating a search with an IF condition that excluded ITEM_NAME and it worked, but the it made the search so "laggy" due to perfomance issues.)

EDIT

Change the name of the variables to make it less confusing (both with the same name) and added an explaining for easier understanding

Also, due to copyright issues that i can't post the exact code here.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `where` clause:

```
WHERE ITEM_TESTE = isnull(@ITEM_TESTE, ITEM_TESTE)
```

This `where` clause will *never* be true when `ITEM_TESTE` is `NULL`, because `NULL = NULL` evaluates to not true in the SQL world.

Presumably, you want:

```
WHERE (ITEM_TEST = @ITEM_TESTE OR @ITEM_TESTE IS NULL)
```

Comment: I've tried that, but the result is the same of the isnull action, it only returns the not null variables, also, the WHERE clause can be true when ITEM_TESTE = NULL due to the fact that the ITEM_TESTE is a variable and i'm searching for a possibility where NULL is valid

Comment: @user4624894 . . . In databases, almost any comparison to `NULL` is never  true, except `is null`.  So, to repeat, `WHERE ITEM_TESTE = NULL` will return *nothing*, because equality to `NULL` is never true.

Comment: I missed one thing when i wrote there... The isnull function doesn't exist with that same writing to stop the NULL return? I mean
isnull(@ITEM_TESTE, ITEM_TESTE) would stop the function to be @ITEM_TESTE, in case he is null, to return ITEM_TESTE, wouldn't it?

Comment: i've changed the description to make it a easier understanding

Comment: @Gui . . . That is only one one side of the comparison.  If either value is `NULL`, then the comparison fails.

Comment: i understand what you are saying, but even if it is that, it's not working and still returning only the values that aren't setted to NULL, while i do need to work with all theses values.

Answer (score 0):

The way it was explained to me and has forever stuck after all of these years, is that NULL is not *nothing*, it is *unknown*, so you cannot use an equality check to verify two things you know nothing about are equally nothing. *IS* is checking that they are in the same *unknown* state, which has nothing to do with a value.

So as the others have said = NULL will never work, because = implies value comparison.

Comment: I do know that, but isn't it the case? I mean, if the information is NULL, is unknown to us, which is okay in this case since is an information that we do not need to know, what i do need, it is to return it even if we do not know it's value.